# Memorize random pick from Table

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I'm using this method for random picking a cell from a Table:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * example.length)
```

and it works without a problem.

But I need to memorize my choice so I could pick again that cell later in my project.

Is there any method to do this thing?

edit: 
I'm using this method in a test script:

```
lvwPrivilegestable().click(
    atCell(atRow((int)Math.floor(Math.random() * orderTable.getRowCount())), 
    atColumn((int)Math.floor(Math.random() * orderTable.getColumnCount()))));
```

So I could click at a cell in a table when I playback my test. And I want to click at the same cells later.

Answer:

It seems that camus was right. Passing the result to a variable and then reading it afterwards resolved my problem. I thought it would be a little more complicated.

edit:

Now, is there a method to pick at random a different cell everytime?
Because using my method there is a chance to pick the same cells sometimes.

Comment: Do you need to access it later on the same page, or later on some other page?

Comment: I'm picking, for example, 5 elements from a table, but later I want to pick the same 5 elements from that table. Does this make any sense?

Comment: how about putting the result of the picking in a variable ?then getting the content of that variable when you need it ?

Comment: Well, I'm using this method in a test script: lvwPrivilegestable().click(atCell(atRow((int)Math.floor(Math.random() * orderTable.getRowCount())), atColumn((int)Math.floor(Math.random() * orderTable.getColumnCount())))); so I could click at a cell in a table when I playback my test. And I want to click at the same cells later.

Comment: Thank you camus, your solution was simple and worked, I tought it will be a little more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a small utility object which can remember random numbers:

```
function replayRandom() {
var results = [];
var replay = false;

return {
  replay: function() {
    replay = true;
  },
  next: function() {
    if (!replay) {
      val = Math.random();
      results.push(val);
      return val;
    }
    val = results[0];
    results.shift();
    return val;
  }
};
}
```

Example:

```
r = replayRandom();
r.next();
0.7939797908670404
>>> r.next();
0.6103413074215163
>>> r.replay();
>>> r.next();
0.7939797908670404
>>> r.next();
0.6103413074215163
```